# Run GraphicsMagick compare command using im4java + gm4java

Tags: java, graphicsmagick, im4java

I am trying to do a GraphicsMagick compare using im4java and gm4java. The GraphicsMagick command I'm using is like this:

```
gm compare -maximum-error 0 -metric MAE -highlight-style xor -hilight-color red -file C:/output/diffFile.pdf C:/input/file1.pdf C:/input/file2.pdf
```

I'm trying to translate that into Java. I know that im4java was originally built for ImageMagick and their commands may differ. Is it possible to run the above compare using im4java plus gm4java?

I've tried this:

```
SimpleGMService service = new SimpleGMService();
service.setGMPath("C:/path/to/graphicsMagick/gm.exe");

try
{
    GMConnection connection = service.getConnection();
    try {
        GMBatchCommand command = new GMBatchCommand(service, "compare");
        // create the operation, add images and operators/options
        IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
        op.metric("MAE");
        op.addRawArgs("-file C:/output/diffFile.pdf");
        op.addImage();
        op.addImage();

        ArrayListOutputConsumer output = new ArrayListOutputConsumer();
        command.setOutputConsumer(output);

        //debug
        command.createScript("C:/output/myscript.bat",op);

        command.run(op, "C:/input/file1.pdf", "C:/input/file2.pdf");

....
```

The above gives me the error:

```
org.im4java.core.CommandException: compare: Unrecognized option (-file C:/output/diffFile.pdf)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attain this by using im4java alone or im4java+gm4java. What gm4java gives you is the performance when you need to process a large number of images.

The problem you are getting is due to the improper use of the `addRawArgs()` method. Each argument you have in your command line needs to be added as individual arguments instead of all together in one string.

Try:

```
op.addRawArgs("-file", "C:/output/diffFile.pdf");
```

Comment: Thanks Kenneth! You are right, I was not using the addRawArgs method correctly. I am building a regression tester which will eventually need to process a lot of files so gm4java may come in handy. It's awesome that you were able to create it!

Comment: @Chuck, glad that I can help and happy to know that gm4java will be useful to you.

Comment: @ben, Thank you for editing the answer. It reads much better now.